# How to get default Android Home screen package and activity name

Tags: android, adb, appium

I know that we can get Package and Activity names by using "**adb shell dumpsys window windows**" and get values from mFocusedApp.

But when i just connect my device and trying to get package and activity names, for that i am getting
**appPackage** as **com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox**
**appActivity** as **com.google.android.launcher.GEL**

But these values doesnt seemed to be right. When use the above in Appium tool, the tool is malfunctioned.

Can someone tell me how to get these package or activity name?

Comment: you can make a background service that will print package name of current running task , this way whenever you visit any app or screen in your device you will get to know the name of it. Note: For different versions of Android method is different to determine current running tasks.

Comment: Why you need Android home screen package name and activity name ?

Answer (score 7):

The `adb shell` command to show the *default launcher activity* in Android 7.0+ without having to bring the launcher app to the front is:

```
adb shell cmd shortcut get-default-launcher
```

Also `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL` is a legitimate activity. So whatever *malfunction* you experienced - take it to the *Appium* developers.

Comment: I am using Android 6.0 and when try with above command, shows me cmd not found. Any other solutions? Does the above command returns packagename and activityname?

Comment: Did you miss the part of my answer where I tried to explain that whatever method you used to get the activity name worked just fine and whatever problem you are experiencing is caused by something else?